# Notepad opens stale file after Set-Content

Tags: powershell, file-io

I have the following code in a script:

```
Set-Content -Path $myFile -Value $myContent
```

Later in the script, I wish to show the end result by opening the file in Notepad:

```
notepad $myFile
```

I find that the file I see that is launched has the original content, not the one I set in the script. The actual file has the correct content, so it's just a matter of getting stale file content.

I've only noticed this behavior when I started working with a large file, so I think I need to flush or wait after setting the content.

One workaround I found is to use the `-PassThru` parameter:

```
$dummy = Set-Content -Path $myFile -Value $myContent -PassThru
```

However, I find that this takes quite a long time. Is this the trade-off I have to deal with?

Comment: You're suggesting that `Set-Content` operates _asynchronously_ (which would definitely be unexpected), but I personally see no evidence of that on W10 with PSv5.1, using a command such as `'hi' > t.txt; 1..100000 | set-content t.txt; notepad t.txt`. What is your environment, and can you provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, `-PassThru` collects all output to be written to the file _in memory_ (again), which is problematic with large files.

Comment: That was just my hypothesis. Maybe it's not Set-Content itself, but something else.

Comment: And regarding your comment on -PassThru, yes, of course, it collects all the output in memory again. Problematic? In what way, other than the fact that it's wasteful and unnecessary?

Comment: Re collecting again: Yes, only problematic in the wasteful / unnecessary sense.

Comment: As for the complete example, do you need my large file for the example to be more complete?

Comment: No, we need more diagnostic information; first and foremost: what PS version, what Windows version? Then, if it's really about the size of the file and `SetContent`, then any algorithmically constructed large file - such as the one in my original comment - should exhibit the symptom. The thing to strive for in any SO question is an MCVE.